# Runtime of triple nested for loops

Tags: performance, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I'm currently going through "Cracking the coding interview" textbook and I'm reviewing Big-O and runtime. One of the examples were as such:

> Print all positive integer solutions to the equation a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 where a, b, c, d are integers between 1 and 1000.

The psuedo code solution provided is:

```
n = 1000;
for c from 1 to n
  for d from 1 to n
    result = c^3 + d^3
    append (c,d) to list at value map[result]

for each result, list in map
  for each pair1 in list
    for each pair2 in list
      print pair1, pair2

The runtime is O(N^2)
```

I'm not sure how O(N^2) is obtained and after extensive googling and trying to figure out why, I still have no idea. My rational is as following:

1. Top half is O(N^2) because the outer loop goes to n and inner loop executes n times each.
2. The bottom half I'm not sure how to calculate, but I got O(size of map) * O(size of list) * O(size of list) = O(size of map) * O(size of list^2).
3. O(N^2) + O(size of map) * O(size of list^2)

> The 2 for loops adding the pairs to the list of the map = O(N) * O(N) b/c it's 2 for loops running N times.
>
> The outer for loop for iterating through the map = O(2N-1) = O(N) b/c the size of the map is 2N - 1 which is essentially N.
>
> The 2 for loops for iterating through the pairs of each list = O(N) * O(N) b/c each list is <= N
>
> Total runtime: O(N^2) + O(N) * O(N^2) = O(N^3)
>
> Not sure what I'm missing here

Could someone help me figure out how O(N^2) is obtained or why my solution is incorrect. Sorry if my explanation is a bit confusing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first part of the solution, sum(size of lists) == N. This means that the second part (nested loop) cannot be more complex then O(N^2). As you said, the complexity is `O(size of map)*O(size of list^2)`, but it should rather be:

`O(size of map)*(O(size of list1^2) + O(size of list2^2) + ... )`

This means, that in the worst-case scenario we will get a map of size 1, and one list of size N, and the resulting complexity of `O(1)*O((N-1)^2) <==> O(N^2)`

In other scenarios the complexity will be lower. For instance if we have map of 2 elements, then we will get 2 lists with the total size of N. So the result will then be:

`O(2)*( O(size of list1^2) + O(size of list2^2)), where (size of list1)+(size of list2) == N`

and we know from basic maths that X^2 + Y^2 <= (X+Y)^2 for positive numbers.

Comment: But there can't be 1 sum with all the possible integers from 1 to 1000, so how would the worst case of having a map of size 1 be possible?

Comment: We are just talking hipothetically here. Of course in this concrete case there cannot be just one list. I used this worst-case example to better illustarte the explaination. In math this is called proof by induction.

Comment: How I've thought of worse-case scenario is a scenario that can potentially happen. I've never thought about it in this context without seeing the answer first. I'll keep thinking about this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you think you can take a look at my comment under my question and explain why my rationale doesn't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the second part is `O(sum of (length of lists)^2 in map)`, since the length of the list varies depending on the we know that `sum of length of lists in map` is n^2 since we definitely added n^2 pairs in the first bit of the code. Since `T(program) = O(n^2) + O(sum of length of lists in map) * O(sum of length of lists in map / size of map) = O(n^2) * O(sum of length of lists in map / size of map)`, it remains to show that `sum of length of lists in map / size of map` is O(1). Doing this requires quite a bit of number theory and unfortunately I can't help you there. But do check out these links for more info on how you would go about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274816/numbers-that-can-be-expressed-as-the-sum-of-two-cubes-in-exactly-two-different-w
http://oeis.org/A001235

Comment: Could you explain why we're dividing sum of length of lists in map by size of map? I understand that the 2 for loops iterating through the pairs in the list are  O(N^2) total because the size of each list is <= N, but not sure about the for loop for the map itself.

The 2 for loops adding the pairs to the list of the map = O(N) * O(N)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question! [cdo256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8033861/cdo256) made some good points, I will try to explain a bit more and complete the picture.

It is more or less obvious that the key questions are - how many integers exist that can be expressed as a sum of two positive cubes in `k` different ways (where `k >= 2`), and what is the possible size of `k` ? This number determines the sizes of lists which are values of `map`, which determine the total complexity of the program. Our "search space" is from 2 to 2 * 10^9 because `c` and `d` both iterate from 1 to 1000, so the sum of their cubes is at most 2 * 10^9. If none of the numbers in the range [2, 2 * 10^9] could be expressed as a sum of two cubes in more than one way, than the complexity of our program would be `O(n^2)`. Why? Well, first part is obviously `O(n^2)`, and the second part depends on the size of lists which are values of `map`. But in this case all lists have size 1, and there are `n^2` keys in map which gives `O(n^2)`.

However, that is not the case, there is a famous example of "taxicub number" 1729, so let us return to our main question - the number of different ways to express an integer as a sum of two cubes of positive integers. This is an active field of research in number theory, and great summary is given in Joseph H. Silverman's article [Taxicabs and Sums of Two Cubes](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/silverman331-340.pdf). I recommend to read it thoroughly. Current records are given [here](http://www.christianboyer.com/taxicab/). Some interesting facts:

- smallest integer that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes of positive integers in three different ways is 87,539,319
- smallest integer that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes of positive integers in four different ways is 6,963,472,309,248 (> 2*10^9)
- smallest integer that can be expressed as a sum of two cubes of positive integers in six different ways is 24,153,319,581,254,312,065,344 (> 2*10^9)

As you can easily see e.g. [here](http://oeis.org/A001235/b001235.txt), there are only 2184 integers in range [2, 2 * 10^9] that are expressible as a sum of two positive cubes in two or three different ways, and for `k = 4,5,..` these numbers are out of our range. Therefore, the number of keys in map is very close to `n^2`, and sizes of the value lists are at most 3, which implies that the complexity of the code

```
  for each pair1 in list
    for each pair2 in list
      print pair1, pair2
```

is constant, so the total complexity is again `O(n^2)`.